# Randomly select argmax of non-unique maximum

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

Given a 2D numpy array, I want to construct an array out of the column indices of the maximum value of each row. So far, `arr.argmax(1)` works well. However, for my specific case, for some rows, 2 or more columns may contain the maximum value. In that case, I want to select a column index randomly (not the first index as it is the case with `.argmax(1)`).

For example, for the following `arr`:

```py
arr = np.array([
    [0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0],
    [2, 1, 3],
    [3, 2, 2]
])
```

there can be two possible outcomes: `array([1, 0, 2, 0])` and `array([1, 1, 2, 0])` each chosen with 1/2 probability.

I have code that returns the expected output using a list comprehension:

```py
idx = np.arange(arr.shape[1])
ans = [np.random.choice(idx[ix]) for ix in arr == arr.max(1, keepdims=True)]
```

but I'm looking for an optimized numpy solution. In other words, how do I replace the list comprehension with numpy methods to make the code feasible for bigger arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some advice I got offline, it turns out that randomization of maximum values are possible when we multiply the boolean array that flags row-wise maximum values by a random array of the same shape. Then what remains is a simple `argmax(1)` call.

```py
# boolean array that flags maximum values of each row
mxs = arr == arr.max(1, keepdims=True)
# random array where non-maximum values are zero and maximum values are random values
random_arr = np.random.rand(*arr.shape) * mxs
# row-wise maximum of the auxiliary array
ans = random_arr.argmax(1)
```

A timeit test shows that for data of shape `(507_563, 12)`, this code runs in ~172 ms on my machine while the loop in the question runs for 11 sec, so this is about 63x faster.

Answer (score 1):

Use `scipy.stats.rankdata` and `apply_along_axis` as follows.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import rankdata
ranks = rankdata(-arr, axis = 1, method = "min")
func = lambda x: np.random.choice(np.where(x==1)[0])
idx = np.apply_along_axis(func, 1, ranks)

print(idx)
```

It returns [1 0 2 0] or [1 1 2 0].

The main idea is `rankdata` calculates ranks of every value in each row, and the maximum value will have 1. `func` randomly choices one of index whose corresponding value is 1. Finally, `apply_along_axis` applies the `func` to every row of `arr`.

Comment: I don't think `apply_along_axis` with a lambda is any faster than a simple list comprehension

Comment: This is indeed slower than the loop I have in the question for my real data. I appreciate the answer though. Upvoted it. Cheers.